# Do I have Direct Mount or Hanger Mount?

Tags: gears, derailleur-rear

I'm very very new to bicycles and obtained a little project for me to work on, hence the amount of rust on the parts currently but I'm not sure if I have a direct or hanger mount derailleur? I'm 100% I need Shimano I just can't figure out which Mount haha.

I have attached a picture to the post (don't mind the disgraceful amount of rust and whatnot). Any help is appreciated![image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a Direct Mount derailleur.  The hanger there is a separate part that is part of the frame.  When companies call them Hanger Mount or hanger style, the hanger is built into the derailleur and not removable.  To replace it, order the Direct Mount one.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the help I was pretty sure it was a direct Mount but I thought I definitely need a second opinion before I have to shell out twice!

Comment: Actually, this is standard mount. Direct mount is a new thing and not everyone knows what it is. See https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/technologies/component/details/direct-mount-rear-derailleur.html

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer provided by CardMechanic which is spot on, note that you don't HAVE to get a Shimano replacement, there are other brands that will also work in it's place.Many entry level derailleurs are also sold with removable hangers to work with both direct mount and hanger mount derailleurs.

Also to further illustrate the difference:

***Long cage* derailleur without hanger**:[image]

***Short Cage* derailleur with hanger**:
[image]

Shimano uses a 2 to 1 pull ratio on its derailleurs and drivetrain parts while Sram uses a 1 to 1 on most parts, but does offer some entry level stuff in 2 to 1 such as the MRX series.

Sunrace also uses a Shimano compatible 2 to 1 ratio as well so any of their 7 speed rear derailleurs would likely work as well.

Further more you may also note that while this is a direct mount derailleur, the silver portion it bolts to is a frame hanger and is also replaceable should the need ever rise. You would just need to know the model of the frame and year to find a replacement, but the one you have looks to be straight. They are made to avoid damage to the frame should your derailleur come in contact with a rock or other debris. Welcome to the fold and happy riding!

Comment: Thank you for the info, should definitely come in handy later on in my adventures. 

Comment: "uses a 2 to 1 ratio"  .. ratio of what to what? @natewengert

Comment: added the word pull, cable pull ratio, meaning the amount of cable that is pulled while the lever/shifter is depressed. Meaning if you had a Sram shifter with 1 to 1 pull ratio and a Shimano derailleur with a 2 to 1, your shift/gears would be misaligned and would not function as intended if at all